# Exibir informações do SQL na view C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, mvc, controller

Essa é minha Model de 'Combo' que tem relação com as models de Lanche e Bebida.

```
    [Required]
    public Lanche Lanche { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Bebida Bebida { get; set; }
```

Essa é a minha Controller

```
    public IActionResult CadastroCombo()
    {
        _contexto.Lanche.ToList();
        _contexto.Bebida.ToList();
        
        return View();
        
    }
```

Essa é a minha View do CadastroCombo (a parte de bebida é igual)

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.lanche.Nome">
    <option selected value="">--Selecione um Lanche--</option>

    @foreach (var nomeLanche in @Model.lanche.Nome)
    {
        <option value="@(nomeLanche)">  @(nomeLanche)   </option>
    }

</select>
```

Ao acessar a view CadastroCombo ja compilando, da o erro de NullReferenceException, pois está retornando null, não estou sabendo chamar o que desejo no banco de dados.

Minha dúvida é como "fazer a chamada".
Fiz algumas pesquisas e li alguma coisa sobre 'public JsonResult exemplo()'

Gostaria de uma dica do que pesquisar, se 'JsonResult' estou no caminho certo.  Vou continuar pesquisando sobre.

Bom, desde já agradeço a qualquer ajuda/dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não entendi muito bem sua duvida.
Entretanto a sua classe Combo não possui lista de Bebidas nem Lanches, mas sim apenas uma entidade de cada.
Se você quiser exibir uma lista o interessante seria criar uma ViewModel com o seguinte codigo:

```
public class ComboViewModel{
public IList<Lanche> Lanche { get; set; }    
public IList<Bebida> Bebida { get; set; }
public ComboViewModel{
Lanche = new List<Lanche>();
Bebida = new List<Bebida>();
}}
```

E depois buscar do DB os dados e atribuir essas duas listas antes de enviar para a view.

Comment: Eu estudei mais e consegui resolver! Mas muito obrigado pela resposta!
Coloquei esse projeto no GitHub e consegui meu primeiro emprego na área!

Answer (score 1):

Faz deste modo...
Na sua controller:

```
 public IActionResult CadastroCombo()
 {
        //Cria lista para carregar na view
        ViewBag.Lanches = new SelectList(_contexto.Lanche.ToList(), "Id", "NomeLanche");
        ViewBag.Bebidas = new SelectList(_contexto.Bebida.ToList(), "Id", "NomeBebida");
        
        return View();
 }
```

A ideia acima é carregar em uma ViewBag uma lista (SelectList) com seus dados do banco de dados... onde tem "Id" e "NomeLanche" você coloca o seu ID do lanche e a coluna do nome.

E na sua view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("LancheId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Lanches, "-- selecione um lanche --", new { @class="form-control" })
```

O dropdown para as bebidas é na mesma ideia dos lanches..
Onde tem "LancheId" no dropdown você troca pelo ID que vc cadastrou no banco como chave para identificar o lanche...

Comment: Muito obrigado! Me ajudou demais!! Consegui resolver com sua ajuda 